# getting lat and lng from device's location

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have some restaurants data in my database including their locations lat and lng. I want to fetch them based on devices locations lat and lng.  suppose I  am visiting from X city. It should show nearest restaurants of that city. when I visit from Y city, it will show nearest restaurants from that city. how can I implement it in express js?

Comment: Please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should elaborate what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
data = mongo_db.restaurants.find_one({'location': {'$near':[lat,long]}})
```

Try  $near. Please check this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: I know that. But I need lat and lng of device location in order to use near

Comment: Yes so first fetch device location n pass it to this api.Here assuming that location column consist of restaurant lat,long. Please share how are you passing lat long to express